# Problem in understanding definition of the limit

Tags: calculus

what i want to ask is that, today i am going with the definition of limit in one variable calculus but i am not adequate with my understandings , my problem is that why in the definition of a limit we assert that if $\lvert x-a\rvert  < \delta$  then $\lvert f(x)-L\rvert <\epsilon$,my question is that why do not we say that $\lvert f(x)-L\rvert<\epsilon$ then $\lvert x-a\rvert\ < \delta$

Comment: A function can have multiple inputs with the same output. You cannot, therefore, let the input depend on the output.

Answer (score 2):

In order top catch the intuitive content that for $x\approx a$ we want $f(x)\approx L$.

Comment: yeah after mikhails comment i understood your comment more intuitively.

Answer (score 1):

This is most easily understood in terms of a trough-and-trap game: if you want to trap the value of the function within a given narrow "trap", you need to feed it the values from a suitably narrow "trough" around $a$. Therefore the choice of the input has to precede the output rather than vice versa.

But the most useful intuition about this is to think that $x$ being infinitely close to $a$, or $x\approx a$, always causes $f(x)$ to be infinitely close to $L$, or $f(x)\approx L$. This approach is formalized in Keisler's wonderful textbook [*Elementary Calculus*](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html).

Comment: i think i am catching your point of view by understanding that a function gives output for every input but not conversely.anyway thankuh so much